# Русский язык- это наречие восточнолитвинского языка?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, история

Является ли современный русский язык наречием восточнолитвинского (беларуского) языка или на него также сказалось влияние украинского (руського) языка?

Comment: Назвать сформировавшийся язык наречием — это неграмотность или издевательство?

Comment: @М_Г Автор вопроса поставил к нему метку "этимология" (см. историю правок). Так что судите сами :)

Answer (score 3):

Современный русский язык не является "наречием" каких-либо других языков, равно как и белорусский с украинским. Это связано прежде всего с тем, что народы, говорящие на этих языках, составляют населения разных стран.

Существуют различные лингвистические критерии разграничения диалекта и языка. По одному из них русский язык может считаться диалектом украинского, украинский диалектом белорусского, белорусский диалектом русского и т. д. (Это связано с тем, что слова из стословного списка изменились незначительно.) Как мне кажется, этот критерий несовершенен и нельзя руководствоваться исключительно им.

Исторически, конечно, все три языка являются потомками (диалектами) древнерусского (общевосточнославянского, если угодно).

Comment: Строрусский-это искажённый старобеларуский, который освоили фино-угры и татары жившие на территории Московии и иных земель Орды. Первая грамматика, первый "Букварь" руського (с одним -с) были напечатаны литвинами (беларусами) как и 1-я руССкая книга. Поэтому был изначально только беларуский (руський) язык,от которого произошёл и руССкий.

Comment: @Гартны Вам, конечно, виднее.

Comment: @Гартны ну конечно, финно-угры вместе с татарами взяли — и вдруг освоили "старобеларуский", как иначе-то! Неважно, что никаких следов "беларусы" в финно-угорских и татарском языках не оставили... Первая грамматика русского (с двумя *эс*, мы же с вами не на украинской мове, упаси боже) языка была написана Генрихом Лудольфом, а вовсе не какими-то там абстрактными литвинами-"беларусами". О происхождении русского языка от белорусского уже и спорить смешно...

Comment: Первая грамматика руського языка (старобеларуского) была напечатана в 1619 году. А немец Лудольф в своей грамматике разделял руССкий и язык славян (украинский и беларуский) так руССкий -это койне, который освоили и по своему исказили фино-угры (меря, мордва, мокша, голядь) Московии и татары  Казанского,Астраханского, Крымского ханства, Нагайской орды и прочих земель населённых тюрками,позже ставшие составной частью РИ жители которой стали все поголовно зваться руССкими на западный манер.(ведь даже немец им грамматику придумал)).

Comment: @Гартны не хочу вас расстраивать, но «руський» язык это и есть русский )) А что вы дальше написали разбирать не хочется. Похоже, вам интересен лишь троллинг.

Comment: @Aer извините,но называть факты "троллингом"- это как минимум несерьёзно. Я такого от Вас не ожидал. И в таком случае до меня,Вас протроллил сам Даль:"бѣлоруссы вдвинулись пѣшкомъ до Москвы — обрусѣвшіе стали говорить нѣсколько иначе, а сѣверъ сохранилъ говоръ ближайшій къ южному, колыбели своей."

Comment: @Гартны не нужно извинений. Пока, кроме фантастических историй о протобелорусской расе, вы ничего не написали. Они фантастические хотя бы потому, что вы не привели ни единого достоверного научного источника. Непонятно, к чему вы процитировали Даля, ведь ни о языковом смешении, ни о первой грамматике русского языка в его словах не говорится.